# Python, using list of lists to update a self made board

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to put my list "Grid" into the board so whenever the user gives what column and row they want to fire at, it will update the guess onto the board. Any help on this?

```
def displayGrid(Rows,Columns):
    output = ' |'
    if (Rows >= 10) or (Columns >= 27):
        print("Please pick a Row less than 10 or a number less than 27")

    else:    
        for title in range(97,97+Columns):
            output = output + chr(title)
            output = output + ' |'
        print(output.upper())

        for row in range(Rows):
            output = str(row+1) + '| '
            for col in range(Columns):
                output = output + ' | '
            print(output)

displayGrid(Rows, Columns)

GuessRow = int(input("What row do you guess? \n"))
GuessColumn = int(input("What column do you guess? \n"))

def userGuess(GuessRow, GuessColumn):
    grid = []
    for row in range(Rows):
        grid.append([])
        for col in range(Columns):
            grid[row].append('')
    grid[GuessRow-1][GuessColumn-1] = 'X'
    print(grid)

userGuess(GuessRow, GuessColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple example functions. `create_grid` creates an empty grid of zeros. `update_grid` updates the specified index to an `X`. I find pprint helpful for nicely formatting nested tables. Also checkout [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) library when you are working on output.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp


def create_grid(numRows,numColumns):
    grid = []

    for row in range(numRows):
        row = []
        for column in range(numColumns):
            row.append(0)
        grid.append(row)

    return grid


def update_grid(grid, guessRow, guessColumn):
    grid[guessColumn][guessRow] = 'X'


numRows = 7
numColumns = 7
grid = create_grid(numRows,numColumns)
pp(grid)

guessRow = 5
guessColumn = 2
update_grid(grid, guessRow, guessColumn)
pp(grid)
```